# Screen brightness not working - KDE

Tags: kubuntu, dell, kde, brightness

Screen brightness is not working as it should.

When I use the hotkeys, the window (?) for screen brightness shows up, and the indicator moves, but it does not affect the brightness of either screen at all. I had the same issue when I was running Manjaro. I'm thinking the issue is either with KDE or with my hardware.

I'm using a DELL XPS laptop with an external monitor and I'm running Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.  (*the age of the software stack in use can have a huge influence on this, currently we have no idea what software you've attempted to use*).

Comment: Does brightness fail to work for your built-in monitor, external monitor or both ? If only for external, I wouldn't expect it works anyway... I use Ubuntu, but also macOS and Windows with plenty of external monitors at work and home, and the brightness never affect these external monitors anyway. There are usually controls on the external monitor to adjust their brightness...

Comment: It fails for both monitors. It dont work when i dont have external monitor connected either